# Managing deployment in KIE Workbench

Tags: mysql, drools, kie, kie-workbench, drools-kie-workbench

I have setup KIE workbench and everything is running fine. I am unable to understand how to manage the deployments in the production environment. I have to do two things.

1. How to manage users/roles/groups in dev and prod environment. I have users/roles/groups and project setup in dev environment. Is there a better way to deploy the same settings to production?
2. I have created some rules in dev environment. What is the best way to backup my data and deploy on production.

Answer (score 1):

I can speak from experience. I have installed KIE Workbench both in dev as in prod. I've used the same method to manage the users/roles in prod as well as in dev.

As for the rules, what I do is I clone the repository from the dev environment to my local machine and then I upload the files individually to the workbench in prod (e.g., drl files). It is not very efficient but it works.

Comment: How about managing users/roles? What is the use of Data Source in KIE? I tried connecting MYSQL but it is not saving any data in it.

Comment: What application server are you using? Wildfly?
Regarding data sources I can't help you. The DB connection in my case is being done on a java application, not directly through the workbench

Comment: I am using Wildfly.

Comment: To manage users you run the .bat file (add-user) in the 'wildfly/bin' folder and configure them from there. It's the same procedure for both environments

Comment: Yes. I have done that. I was just trying to find out the DevOps for KIE, like how to automate the deployment from dev to prod environment. But, It seems like I have to write scripts to move the data/files from dev to prod manually.

Comment: Maybe someone might know how to do that. Due to the fact that time is always scarce, I chose to handle that by myself manually. It works. Cheers